# how to send values from action class and view in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

```js
 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
         FindBean lb=(FindBean)form;
        String bldgrp=lb.getBldgrp();
        String city=lb.getCity();
        String locality=lb.getLocality();
        String state=lb.getState();
        
        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web","root","password");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select name,email,phone from register where bldgrp = '" + bldgrp + "'AND state ='" + state + "'AND city ='" + city + "'AND locality ='" + locality + "'");

while(rs.next())
{

}
            
   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
{
out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

i want that result stored in Resultset object rs is shown on next jsp page. i am using struts in netbeans ide

Comment: set the object in the request attribute in your action class and fetch the same from the request in the forwarded jsp. please google you will find your answer quicker than here

Comment: can u elaborate more please help me

Comment: Just store the resultSet in the session.

Comment: please please elaborate more with code examples or provide me link please buddy help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("myResultSet", rs);
```

In you jsp:

```
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)session.getAttribute("myResultSet");
```

Just store the object in the session and retrieve in your jsp. See above.

Comment: should i use <%  %> this tag to use resultset query in jsp page and also for printing

Comment: @user2976141 Yes the java part of the jsp code will go inside <% %>

Comment: i have used the method but in jsp page its showing error 'HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 17 in the jsp file: /Findresult.jsp
ResultSet cannot be resolved to a type
14:     </head>
15:     <body>
16:         <h1>H World!</h1>
17:         <% ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)session.getAttribute("myResultSet");%>
18:     </body>
19: </html>

Answer (score 2):

Send it as an attribute of the HttpServletRequest, check [setAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method

```
request.setAttribute("here_the_name",here_the_object);
```

In your JSP page, you can extract it with the [getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
Object o = request.getAttribute("here_the_name");
```

You can send any object, you have just to cast it.

Answer (score 2):

Find the below action code

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select name,email,phone from register where bldgrp = '" + bldgrp + "'AND state ='" + state + "'AND city ='" + city + "'AND locality ='" + locality + "'");
Myobject obj = new MyObject();

while(rs.next()) {
    obj.setName(rs.getString(1));
    obj.setEmail(rs.getString(2));
    obj.setPhone(rs.getString(3));

}

request.setAttribute("myObj", obj);
```

in jsp:

```
<logic:present name="myObj">
Name : <bean:write name="myObj" property="name"/>
Email : <bean:write name="myObj" property="email"/>
Phone : <bean:write name="myObj" property="phone"/>
</logic:present>
```

Hopes this may be helpful ..

Comment: @AnkitKushwaha it is an example how to send the values from action to jsp.